# nginx: run bash script on POST as specific user

Tags: git, nginx, githooks

I have a nginx and git servers on one CentOS host, my git repo on bitbucket. What I wanna do is to execute a bash script, when specific POST request is received from Bitbucket.

What I have:

**1)** dedicated user `nginx-script-runner`.

**2)** nginx config:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /main.php?$1;
}
```

**3)** main.php:

```
exec('/bin/bash /script.sh')
```

**4)** /script.sh:

```
sudo -u nginx-script-runner /bin/bash /pull.sh
```

**5)** sudoers:

```
nginx-script-runner ALL=NOPASSWD: /pull.sh
```

`pull.sh` automatically pulls from the remote origin and runs the 'build' procedure. Build procedure depends on `npm`, `bower`, `composer`, `grunt` etc (I also use `nvm` for the node version management). Those tools are meant to be run when there's real user logged in. The thing is — I login to CentOS via PKA only, no passwords, so my `pull.sh` falls under requirement to be able to run it as multiple users (me and `nginx-script-user`). And since it's a git repo, it has `node_modules`, `bower_components`, composer's `vendor` folder I should somehow manage privileges.

**1st problem**: I cannot really run `pull.sh` with different users. Even when I have:

```
DIR='/repo.git'
#chgrp -R tactic "$DIR"
#chmod -R g+w "$DIR"
#find "$DIR" -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
setfacl -R -m g:common-group:rwX "$DIR"
find "$DIR" -type d | xargs setfacl -R -m d:g:common-group:rwX
```

I still end up having loads of "chgrp/chown permission denied" error.

**2nd problem**: I cannot really execute `pull.sh` with either of users from `main.php`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**P.S.**

- Both my personal user (with PKA) and `nginx-script-runner` (password auth only, no external SSH access) belong to common group `common-group`.
- After the git repo was cloned, I've configure it with `git config core.sharedRepository true`  and ran the privileges fix.

Comment: This is meant for deployment. Why does it matter that anyone else besides the deploy user owns files? No one else should be here.

Comment: Well, I used to do it manually. And sometimes it maybe a must to go there and debug the deployment. Although, you gave me a clue. When that happens — I could _possibly_ just `su - nginx-script-runner` and do my stuff. Thanks for the tip @Melvyn

Comment: Ok so, this process is fully automated now and you want to be able to be able to run it manually when it breaks. Then yes, use `sudo -i` or `su`, but it kinda makes the separate nginx-script-runner user less secure, since it now has to be login shell. I would have two environments, one for your debug user and one production, update them both in your web hook, and fix everything in your debug user. Once fixed, you push and things get to production. The overhead will be that you need to keep configuration of those two environments synchronized.

Comment: Again, thanks for the tip @Melvyn, but I guess I'll just stick with `su`. I think if user has only one dedicated group, how much else he could do with his login shell? Also considering that sshd won't allow anything except pubkey authentication. Is it that bad that user has a login shell?